Given two matrices, where the average of correlations for each column is $0$, how to determine the range of average correlation values for each row?
Given two matrices A and B, where $mean(corr(A_{\cdot,i},B_{\cdot,i}))$ is equal to $0$, how to determine the range of $mean(corr(A_{j,\cdot},B_{j,\cdot}))$ ?
